# Is it possible to make one domain be connected to 2 servers?

Tags: dns

Is it possible and how would I do this, to make one domain www.mydomain.com be connected to 2 servers?

**Situation:**

I have Dedicated server on which I am hosting eg. "some game server", and I also have Hosting VPS on which there is my web page. Both servers are alredy connected via tunnel so I can access mySQL DB on the one from another (data exchange).

Now to connect to this "some game server" you need to type "mydomain.com:port" inside of the game.

What I want to do is to when you type www.mydomain.com in browser you will connect to VPS hosting where the web page is, but when you type "mydomain.com:port" (eg. "mydomain.com:14440") in the game you can access dedicated server on which there are actual "some game servers".

Also: There are more than one "some game server" so there are few ports.

I hope you understood what I meant. Thanks for answers!

Comment: Why not add a subdomain with a redirect? `game.mydomain.com`

Comment: You need something called port forwarding, but how you set this up depends on your setup and how much control you have over the various equipment involved. Please provide more detail…

Answer (score 1):

I think the keyword that you are looking for is "load balancing". This is where one server handles the incoming web request and redirects the work to one of an array of available servers. There are several ways to implement load balancing. [Here's a general summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, i asume that:

- mydomain.com in DNS is an A host for "Dedicated server's IP"
- www.mydomain.com is a CNAME to mydomain.com or A to "Dedicated server's IP"

Then, assuming that you are are able to install a Web Server to the "Dedicated server", it would be very simple to setup a transparent proxy to the "Hosting VPS"

Example using Apache:

```
ProxyPass / http://hosting_vps
ProxyPassReverse / http://hosting_vps
```

I also consider routing as a solution but is far more complicated to setup (involves some kind of tunnel and routing table manipulation on both hosts which i see totally undesirable)

Comment: If i just misunderstood, pardon me, your question is ambiguous when talking which domain points where and which server hosts what

Answer (score 0):

An name is resolved to one or more IP addresses. Each IP address is for one computer.

You may hack your router in order to route between two computers depending on the destination port, but this is not recommended.

Port forwarding will slow down your connections to the game.

You'd better declare a "game.mydomain.com" in your DNS, and have your full bandwidth on both servers.